# Vs2017 farseer reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame, farseer

I am trying to open a sample project in the farseer with monogame in vs2017 but all the time I get this error:

```
 internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FarseerPhysicsGame game = new FarseerPhysicsGame())
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is obvious. Your object FarseerPhysicsGame does not implement IDisposable, so it can not be used inside a using statement

Comment: It's funny, because the error messages tell you everything you need to know